# how to store a special kind of data in sql

Tags: python, sql

I have 'N'patient. For all all these patients the basic information like name, gender, age, symptom etc are available. The data contains ECG lead measurements.For single patient 12 different lead values exist. Lead 1, Lead2, Lead3, aVL,aVR,aVF,V1, V2...V6.

My problem is how I can store one patients measurement data in a data base.
Say for Patientid 2004uid ,

nam 28 chestpain are there,

but along with this data, I need to store measurements of each lead. I have separate measurements like this.

LEAD NO QA  QD  SA  S1A SD  S1D RA  R1A RD

```
Lead -1 0   0   0   0   0   0   1.295   0   66.5
Lead -2 0.025   9.5 0   0   0   0   0.775   0   51
Lead -3 0.695   42.5    0.045   0   10.5    0   0.105   0   12
Lead -4 0   0   0   0   0   0   0.965   0   58
Lead -5 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   59
Lead -6 0.2 36  0.025   0   8   0   0.29    0   26
Lead -7 0   0   1.11    0   52  0   0.385   0   33.5
Lead -8 0   0   1.53    0   68.5    0   1   0   35
Lead -9 0   0   1.29    0   50.5    0   0.63    0   30
Lead -10 0  0   0   0.8 0   25  0   2.94    51
Lead -11 0  0.15    20  0.33    0   19  0   3.58    0   
Lead -12 0  0.16    29  0   0   0   0   2.48    0
```

I am not sure about the storing method of this data into a database.

Can some one guide me to solve this issue?

Later I need to read this data in python data frame for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you want to load these data into a database? So which database do you use now?
you should just delimit your rows by a dilimiter such as '\t',then you can load them by the simple load command supplied by the database.
if you use MySQL, like below:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'my_delimitered.data' INTO TABLE mytable (a,b,c...) FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

if you use PostgreSQL, like below:

```
postgres=# \copy mytable(a,b,c...) from 'my_delimitered.data' with delimiter '\t'
```

Comment: i want to save in to mysql. but the data is in java workstation/ variable. it is not available as shown above,I had shown in above example were the mesurements available for a single person with 12 different leads. I need to store 20 measurements columns of 12 different leads into a single DB. and later access them to a python code.

Comment: you can install a MySQL client in your local computer environment, and then use the      conmmand "mysql -h host -D database_name -u username -p password" to connect your mysql database, and then execute the load data command above in the mysql shell.I think this can deal your problem.